# javascript/html NOOB: adding stuff to a document

Tags: javascript, html, append

I'm trying to make a super-simple website which makes me fill in my name and gives a customised greeting as an alert. I now wanted to write the greeting to the HTML document itself, and I have tried `document.write()`, which just wrote over my other code, making only the greeting visible, and `document.add()`(I have no idea what it does, just playing around :P). So I googled this, but could not find anything (thanks to my super-awesome googling skills ;p). So how do I go about appending to end of a document without overwriting everything?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a read around this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp

You are right with what you have so far but reading the above link will point you in the direction you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try the InnerHTML property using the DOM element: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Basically, select the element where you want to append stuff, and do something like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML+="Text stuff";
```

This is the most simple way to do it, I think.

Comment: I have a button before this, so when it runs, it goes like `[button here]Text stuff`. So what of newlines?

Comment: Then put "<br />Text stuff" instead. But this is very basic HTML, when going further you will most likely use paragraphs then (<p></p>)

Answer (score 0):

To just add content, you can [append a new child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to an element such as the [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.body).

```
document.body.appendChild(...);
```

If the content is text, you can [create a text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) to hold it:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(greeting));
```